# Python: Selenium send_key not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium in Python, as as I am a beginner in doing so I cannot get `send_key` to work, but most probably it is straight forward and I am missting something.

Here is an example of what I have done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://semantria.com/demo")
item = driver.find_element_by_id("analyze_url_form")
item.send_keys("http://finance.yahoo.com/news/skystar-bio-pharmaceutical-company-provides-133000048.html")
go_button = driver.find_element_by_id("analyze_url_button")
go_button.click()
```

The idea is that in the `https://semantria.com/demo` website, there is an empty space that one can enter a website link, and then click on the `Go` button.
However, it looks like my code does not do this.

Am I doing something wrong? Does this website do something that I should be aware of and change my code accordingly?
Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending keys to the `form` element, not the `input` element inside.

Plus, you can just send the URL with a new line at the end which is the same as you've entered the URL and pressed `ENTER` key which results in the form being submitted. Works for me:

```
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form#analyze_url_form input[name=link]")
item.send_keys("http://finance.yahoo.com/news/skystar-bio-pharmaceutical-company-provides-133000048.html" + "\n")
```

As a bonus, here is how you can grab the sentiment value (you have to let selenium know what to wait for via `WebDriverWait` and Expected Conditions):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://semantria.com/demo")

item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form#analyze_url_form input[name=link]")
item.send_keys("http://finance.yahoo.com/news/skystar-bio-pharmaceutical-company-provides-133000048.html" + "\n")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

sentiment_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "strong.sentiment_score_value")))
print(sentiment_value.text)
```

Prints `positive (+0.230)`.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked nicely. Can you please tell me now how to look at the content that webpage returns?

Comment: thanks. Where is the whole content of webpage not just the sentiment value?

Comment: @TJ1 if you need the complete content, right after the wait is done (meaning the results are now loaded), get the `driver.page_source`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks alecxe yes that was very helpful I really appreciate it.

Comment: alecxe: can you please also tell me how to write in the text area box and click on start analysis? Do you look at the page source? I really appreciate your help again :)

Comment: @TJ1 let's avoid having a long conversation with follow-up questions in comments - please consider creating a separate topic so that more people can help. Also, throw me a link here. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Thanks alecxe. Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062149/python-selenium-write-in-the-text-box-of-a-form